# How to retry for 404 link not found in scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

Some sites give 404 error temporarily. But I paste in on browser it works.
How to tell scrapy to retry the 404 status code links for 5 times.

Comment: Maybe you are making too many requests using scrapy and sites just returninig 404?

Comment: Even if I try 1 requests per second, it fails sometimes. Is there a way to say in scrapy to retry 404 status?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two Scrapy settings relevant to what you need:

- [RETRY_HTTP_CODES](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:setting-RETRY_HTTP_CODES): you should override the default value in your project to include `404`
- [RETRY_TIMES](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/downloader-middleware.html#retry-times): just set it to `5`