# Scrapy:In a request fails (eg 404,500), how to ask for another alternative request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with scrapy.
In a request fails (eg 404,500), how to ask for another alternative request? Such as two links can obtain price info, the one failed, request another automatically.

Comment: you can write a middleware.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use  "errback" in the Request like

`errback=self.error_handler`

where error_handler is a function (just like callback function) in this function check the error code and make the alternative Request.

see errback in the scrapy documentation:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Comment: Thank you, i have solved this problem by myself, as you said.

Answer (score 10):

Just set `handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 500]` and check for the status code in `parse` method. Here's an example:

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 500]
    name = "my_crawler"

    start_urls = ["http://github.com/illegal_username"]

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.status in self.handle_httpstatus_list:
            return Request(url="https://github.com/kennethreitz/", callback=self.after_404)

    def after_404(self, response):
        print response.url

        # parse the page and extract items
```

Also see:

- [How to get the scrapy failure URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724730/how-to-get-the-scrapy-failure-urls)
- [Scrapy and response status code: how to check against it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698372/scrapy-and-response-status-code-how-to-check-against-it)
- [How to retry for 404 link not found in scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768589/how-to-retry-for-404-link-not-found-in-scrapy)

Hope that helps.

Comment: this doesnt cover total failures , e.g DNS - only when a webserver responds